# How do I resolve "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" error?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I am passing the following via the request object in codeBehind:

Get the Requested code to be created.

```
Dim Code As String = Request("code").ToString()
```

and below is my markup page called `barcodes.aspx`:

```
  <form id="Form1" method="post" runat="server">
  <img src="barcodes.aspx?code=XXXXX" alt="barcode" /> 

   <asp:Image id="myBarCode"  runat="server"></asp:Image>
  </form>
```

Why am I getting the error above?

Comment: This may be an ignorant question, but why would you have querystring values set as part of a source on an image?

Comment: rie819, no such thing as ignorant question. I couldn't figure out where to stick that. That's why I put it there. I am hoping someone will help me fix it. Thanks for the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to actually submit the form (POST) or pass the parameters in the URL (GET) to get the request parameters via the Request object. Two easy ways (of many) to do this:

Option 1. Keep just your `barcodes.aspx` and `barcodes.aspx.vb`. In `barcodes.aspx` put:

```
<form id="Form1" method="post" runat="server">
  <input type="hidden" name="code" value="XXXXX" /> 

  <asp:Image id="myBarCode"  runat="server"></asp:Image>
  <asp:Button runat="server" Text="Submit"></asp:Button>
</form>
```

In `barcodes.aspx.vb` put in the `Page_Load`:

```
If PostBack Then
  Dim code As String = Request.Form("code")
  If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(code) Then
    ' Generate your image here, a code has been specified
  End If
End If
```

Then just hit the submit button on your aspx page.

Option 2. Split it into two aspx pages but basically same as above.

In `submitme.aspx` put this (for a POST, click the button):

```
<form id="Form1" method="post" runat="server">
  <input type="hidden" name="code" value="XXXXX" /> 

  <asp:Button runat="server" Text="Submit" PostBackURL="barcodes.aspx"></asp:Button>
</form>
```

Or this (for a GET, click the link):

```
<a href="barcodes.aspx?code=XXXXX">Click Me</a>
```

In `barcodes.aspx.vb` put this in Page_Load (works for either the GET or POST option):

```
Dim code As String = Request("code")
If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(code) Then
  ' Generate your image here, a code has been specified
End If
```

In `barcodes.aspx` you would then simply need:

```
<asp:Image id="myBarCode"  runat="server"></asp:Image>
```

Comment: Your solution worked Kettch19. Thank you very much.

I may have a question about how to generate this code from the db. 

As it is now, it is hardcoded but I think this is for a different thread.
Again, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3):

If `Request("code")` is null, calling `.ToString()` on it will give you a null reference exception.

Comment: DBM, do you know how I can resolve this? I actually hard-coded a value on the markup like this:   <img src="barcodes.aspx?code=hqcfqs55kioevn55saz0me55" alt="barcode" />. My feeling is I didn't put that line of code at the right place. That's why I am getting the error. Do you know the correct place to put that line of code so it can be read by codebehind?

Answer (score 1):

Check if `Request("code")` is null or not. If it is null, then you will get an object reference error when calling `ToString()`

Comment: Umair, thanks. Please see my response to DBM. Your question is similar to his.

Comment: But when you initially browse to the page in localhost say, what url are you browsing to?? If it is just `barcodes.aspx` then that line will throw an error! The code is not even getting to the stage of rendering the html and sending the image tag with the `barcodes.aspx?code=XXXXX` src. Hope that makes senseth!

Comment: Umair, please bear with me. I am still very new to .net. Do I need to put barcodes.aspx?code=XXXXX in a separate page? barCodes.aspx has a codebehind called barCodes.aspx.vb

Answer (score 1):

I think this has to deal with the fact that you are trying to get the query string value of an image on the page. `Request()` will only get the querystring for the 'requested page', which is the page you are on, not the image itself. Therefore your code will always be null if you are expecting it to pull from the image source

Comment: This is where I am getting this code from: http://www.jensbits.com/2011/06/29/generating-barcodes-with-barcode-generator-and-asp-net-vb/ . Notice where  <img src="barcodes.aspx?code=hqcfqs55kioevn55saz0me55" alt="barcode" /> is placed. Where do I put that code?

Comment: I am not familiar with this product or your project, but what are you hoping to do? once i have this info i can steer you in the right direction

Comment: We have a project where we are trying to scan customer info (firstname, lastname) using a barcode. My task is to generate the barcode so we can use a Pitney Bowes scanning equipment to scan them. According to my boss, Pitney Bowes scanner only recognizes barcodes generated with names, not number. This comes closest to what we need in terms of ease of use and the ability to generate the barcode with names. I just can't get that line of code to work. If I can get it to work, then I will replace the hardcoded value with value from the db.

Comment: it seems to me that you need to put that image on a page other than barcodes.aspx and make sure your code for barcodes.aspx is equal to that of the link you provided. there is also the chance you may need to set up the handler that link mentions

Comment: Thaks a lot peroija. Please, please help me understand this part:   Set your image tag to the path of your barcode.aspx file with the code as a url param. This is from the link you referenced. How is this different from what I did with the markup?

Comment: its the same as your markup. however, what page is your markup on and what page is your `Dim Code As String = Request("code").ToString()` on?

Comment: Sorry, I hope you can still see this and assist. The markup is on BarCode.aspx and Dim Code As... is on BarCode.aspx.vb (codebehind).

Answer (score 0):

You can simply remove ToString(), as Request(item key) returns String:

```
Dim Code As String = Request("code")
```

Answer (score 0):

Check to see that the query string value exists:

```
Dim Code as String = String.Empty
If Not Request.QueryString("code") Is Nothing Then
    Code = Request.QueryString("code")
End If
```

Comment: Please see peroija's response. I think it makes sense. The question becomes, given the response I gave to his response, *where* do I put that line of code so it's value can be read?

Comment: Ah, so in the demo page you referenced it looks like the barcode.aspx is being called to generate an image with the appropriate barcode, using the code passed in to the querystring. The markup for barcode.aspx should be empty, as the rendered output of the page would be generated by the codebehind. Your list of <img> tags (with source set to "barcode.aspx?code=whatever" from your database) has to exist on a different page.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use the string.isnullorempty() function to test the contents of the request.querystring value